# Xamarin.Forms: how to apply a style on a Expander containing an Indicator

Tags: xamarin.forms, datatrigger, expander, indicator

I would like to re use some `Expanders` in a **Xamarin.Forms app**.

The `Expander` uses `Image` as `FontImageSource` to display **chevrons** as `Indicator`, and the `DataTrigger` on the Image allows to switch between up/down chevron:

```
<Expander>
    <Expander.Header>
        <Grid>
            <Label Text="Who we are?"
                    Style="{StaticResource AboutPageCategoryLabelStyle}" />
            <Image
                    HeightRequest="20"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="20">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <FontImageSource
                            FontFamily="FontAwesomeLight"
                            Glyph="{StaticResource FalIconChevronDown}"
                            Size="20"
                            Color="Gray" />
                    </Image.Source>
                    <Image.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger
                            Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                            TargetType="Image"
                            Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <FontImageSource
                                FontFamily="FontAwesomeLight"
                                Glyph="{StaticResource FalIconChevronUp}"
                                Size="20"
                                Color="Gray" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Image.Triggers>
            </Image>
            </Grid>
    </Expander.Header>
    <Expander.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </Expander.ContentTemplate>
</Expander>
```

I've tried to create a `Style` to duplicate easily the same `Expander`, but it doesn't work:

I can define the style of the `Image` for the **"default" indicator mode**:

```
<Style x:Key="ChevronImageForExpander" TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor">Transparent</Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions">End</Setter>
    <Setter Property="VerticalOptions">Center</Setter>
    <Setter Property="HeightRequest">20</Setter>
    <Setter Property="WidthRequest">20</Setter>
    <Setter Property="Source">
        <Setter.Value>
            <FontImageSource Glyph="{StaticResource FalIconChevronDown}"
                                FontFamily="FontAwesomeLight"
                                Size="20"
                                Color="{StaticResource Gray-600}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then in my **View** I apply this style:

```
<Expander>
    <Expander.Header>
        <Grid>
            <Label Text="Header" />
            <Image Style="{StaticResource ChevronImageForExpander}">
            </Image>
        </Grid>
    </Expander.Header>
    <Expander.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Label Text="Cotnent" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Expander.ContentTemplate>
</Expander>
```

This works fine, but **I only have the  "default" indicator image**.

I've tried to define the style through a `Trigger` for the **"expanded" indicator mode**:

```
<Style x:Key="ChevronImageForExpanderTrigger" TargetType="Image">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                        TargetType="Image"
                        Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Source">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <FontImageSource
                        FontFamily="FontAwesomeLight"
                        Glyph="{StaticResource FalIconChevronUp}"
                        Size="20"
                        Color="{StaticResource Gray-600}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This also works fine, but I **only have the  "expanded" indicator image**.

So I've tried to "merge" the 2 styles like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ChevronImageForExpander" TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor">Transparent</Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions">End</Setter>
    <Setter Property="VerticalOptions">Center</Setter>
    <Setter Property="HeightRequest">20</Setter>
    <Setter Property="WidthRequest">20</Setter>
    <Setter Property="Source">
        <Setter.Value>
            <FontImageSource Glyph="{StaticResource FalIconChevronDown}"
                                FontFamily="FontAwesomeLight"
                                Size="20"
                                Color="{StaticResource Gray-600}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Triggers">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                            TargetType="Image"
                            Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Source">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <FontImageSource
                            FontFamily="FontAwesomeLight"
                            Glyph="{StaticResource FalIconChevronUp}"
                            Size="20"
                            Color="{StaticResource Gray-600}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

***But this doesn't work and I get an Exception: "System.InvalidOperationException: The BindableProperty "Triggers" is readonly.".***

I could also create a control, but I would like to use different kinds of content for the `Expander.ContentTemplate`: labels, images, ...

***How should be the better approach to easily reuse this Expander?***

**Edit: add some code for the Style**

Comment: If you want to reuse this Expander,you could try to create a contentview with it.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT yes it's why I've tried to do, but in this case, I need to specify all the `ContentTemplate` that I will use in this `ContentView`: it's not very interesting if I want to  customize the style of the content for an Expander only? I should create the corresponding style in the DataTemplate for only one case, whereas only the style is changing... In the same time, I would like to be able to display social network links, or urls, so I should pass the Command to the ContentView. Isn't there a way to share only the style of the `Header` of the `Expander`?

Comment: Maybe you could just create a contentview for the Header.

Comment: Yes it's what I'm looking for. But as the `Header` contains an `ImageSource`, and a `Trigger` related to a `AncestorType`, I don't see how to achieve this. I'm able to apply a `Style` for the "default" image, but not for the triggered one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was just a problem of Trigger declaration in the "global" style: we must use `<Style.Triggers>` instead of `<Setter Property="Triggers">`

So, like this it works well:

```
<Style x:Key="ChevronImageForExpander" TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor">Transparent</Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions">End</Setter>
    <Setter Property="VerticalOptions">Center</Setter>
    <Setter Property="HeightRequest">20</Setter>
    <Setter Property="WidthRequest">20</Setter>
    <Setter Property="Source">
        <Setter.Value>
            <FontImageSource Glyph="{StaticResource FalIconChevronDown}"
                                FontFamily="FontAwesomeLight"
                                Size="20"
                                Color="{StaticResource Gray-600}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                        TargetType="Image"
                        Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Source">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <FontImageSource
                        FontFamily="FontAwesomeLight"
                        Glyph="{StaticResource FalIconChevronUp}"
                        Size="20"
                        Color="{StaticResource Gray-600}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And in the XAML:

```
<Expander>
    <Expander.Header>
        <Grid>
            <Label Text="Header" />
            <Image Style="{StaticResource ChevronImageForExpander}">
            </Image>
        </Grid>
    </Expander.Header>
    <Expander.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Label Text="Content" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Expander.ContentTemplate>
</Expander>
```

Maybe is there another approach to apply ContentTemplate to the Header (both to the Label and to the Image), but at least, it's correct like this.

Comment: how to xamarin 5.0. on my device, this command is not executable

Comment: my resource: `<Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="LabelBind">
              <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,20,0" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="23"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="angle-up"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>`